# UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingImage not calling in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to load an image from photo library using imagePickerView. I, updated my plist to get access to photo library as below for Xcode 8.

[image]

After, Updated plist.I can get access to photo library. But,Picker image not loading to my imageView.

**My code:**

**Note:** 
Below code use to work in Xcode 7 not in Xcode 8 ?

```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

   let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
   @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        imagePicker.delegate = self
   }

   @IBAction func library(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
   }
```

**Code updated:** from rmaddy answer:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
          imageView.image = image
     }
       picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Swift 3 you need to use the proper delegate method:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: You  Should dismiss Picker before  using image object.. This code will create memory issue on iPhone4s.

Comment: I am using your answer.it works fine but sometime app crashes with memory warning.i don't know why. I am using Swift 3...

Comment: That would be a whole new issue. Post an new question with all relevant details so people can help you solve that issue.